# SAS: multiplyi observations and iterate a column

Tags: sas

I got:

```
data foo;
  length Some_id mileage;
  input Some_id mileage;
  datalines;
1 100
2 200
...
1000 20000
;
```

I want to have each observation to be duplicated and mileage shifted by factor of 1.1 and 0.9 resulting to:

```
data bar
1 90
1 100
1 110
2 180
2 200
2 220
....
```

I can do this with 3x data steps and 2x proc append, but it feels stupid.

Any simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a DO loop.

```
data bar ;
  set foo ;
  do factor = 0.9, 1, 1.1 ;
    new_mileage = factor * mileage;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one step solution,

```
data foo;
  length Some_id mileage 8;
  input Some_id mileage;
  do factor = 0.9, 1.0, 1.1;
    mileage1 = mileage * factor;
    output;
  end;
  drop factor mileage;
  rename mileage1 = mileage;
  datalines;
  1 100
  2 200
  ;
run;
```

Comment: Could the guy explain why you down vote my solution?

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as the one Tom posted. Also `foo` is an example dataset - combining your answer with it doesn't make it better.